# Backbone view/template fails to load from REST

Tags: javascript, php, rest, backbone.js

I have properly coded a simple REST api and several backbone models. My parent model is called `Topic` and child model called `Questions`.

I'm trying to call a get method on the REST api and display the received `Topic` object to the user in a presentable manner. I am receiving the json (can be seen in the network tab on Chrome), but it is not getting sent to the view correctly.

**Model:**

```
var Topic = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: ROOT + '/topic',
    idAttribute: 'topicId',
    initialize: function () {
        this.questions = new Questions([], {parent: this});
    },
    toJSON: function () {
        var json = Backbone.Model.prototype.toJSON.call(this);
        json.questions = this.questions.toJSON();
        return json;
    }
});
var Topics = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Topic,
    url: ROOT + 'topic',
    parse: function (response) {
        return response.results;
    }
})
```

**REST URL:**

`http://localhost/Project/index.php/rest/resource/topic/`

**Backbone View:** This is where I think the error is...(console log below prints an empty object)

```
var TopicListView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: '.page',
      render: function () {
        var that = this;
        var topics = new Topics();
        topics.fetch({
          success: function (topics) {
              console.log(topics);
            var template = _.template($('#topic-list-template').html(), {topics: topics.models});
            that.$el.html(template);
          }
        })
      }
    });
```

**Using the above functions:**

```
var topic = new Topic();
topic.fetch();
topicListView = new TopicListView();

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "home"
    }
});
var router = new Router;

// render topic list for 'home'
router.on('route:home', function () {
    topicListView.render();
});
```

**Edit: Solution:** Overriding the parse function in the collection proved to be the error. I wonder why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument `topics` in your `success` handler is [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the variable `topics`.

The argument contains the parsed JSON response, not the Backbone Collection. You don't need that, so you can remove the argument.

The reference to `topics` will now be to your Collection, so `topics.models` will have the value you expect.

```
topics.fetch({
  success: function () { // argument removed here so `topics` is no longer shadowed
    var template = _.template($('#topic-list-template').html(), { topics: topics.models });
    that.$el.html(template);
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks but it did not work. The problem is the same, I tried `console.log(topics.models);` in the same success function and it is an empty array.

Comment: Ok. Can you post the response to the fetch request?

Comment: From the network tab: `[{"topicId":"1","topicDes":"Music"},{"topicId":"2","topicDes":"Technology"},{"topicId":"3","topicDes":"Keyboards"}]`

Comment: Also, could you pls tell me what the following reference is, in the following line from your code: `var template = _.template($('#topic-list-template').html(), {>>>>>>topics<<<<<<: topics.models });`

Comment: It's the collection that you create with `new Topics()` - my answer didn't show that part.